# Term for not recognizing faces

Tags: single-word-requests

I remember a term for someone who has difficulty remembering faces. I was reading several years ago, *Alice Through the Looking Glass*, and my friend told me that [Humpty Dumpty](http://books.google.com/books?id=5iLX_94aRBUC&printsec=frontcover&dq=alice+through+the+looking+glass&hl=en&src=bmrr&ei=IyZxTquzLIOciAfrgfGgBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Humpty%20Dumpty&f=false) had that disorder(he told me he had read it off somewhere, so I believed there is such a term):

> “The face is what one goes by, generally,” Alice remarked in a thoughtful tone.
>       “That’s just what I complain of,” said Humpty Dumpty. “Your face is the same as everybody has—the two eyes, so      ” (marking their places in the air with his thumb) “nose in the middle, mouth under. It’s always the same. Now if you had the two eyes on the same side of the nose, for instance—or the mouth at the top—that would be some help.

Is there really a term for it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Prosopagnosia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosopagnosia), if you really want to get technical about it.

Comment: "I don't think there are less technical terms for it. :D" - Yes there are... Ignorant, Drunk or Racist :D

Comment: Maybe the second is the one that works best eheh

Comment: @Alenanno -- it's also called "face blindness" and it sucks.  *Pace* osknows,  the face having a different ethnicity doesn't make it more difficult to recognize, but wow, does it make the consequences of failure worse.  "No, you don't 'all look alike' to me.  Well, you do but everybody does..."

Comment: @Malvolio: I don't understand, sorry, why were you writing that to me?

Comment: @Alenno, you wrote "I don't think there are less technical terms"; there is a less-technical term, "face blindness".  The rest of my comment was really for osknows, but stupid E.SE won't let me address two people.

Comment: @Malvolio: Ah ok, because I was thinking I said something bad :D

Answer (score 15):

As @Anita points out, **prosopagnosia** is the technical name of the condition. **Face-blindness** is a widely-used colloquial name for it — for instance, the Harvard and UCL Prosopagnosia Research Center website is at [www.faceblind.org](http://www.faceblind.org).  I have a couple of friends who are somewhat face-blind, and that’s the term they use.